# setTimeout in Javascript / Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to test a fadein and fadeout function that is looping arround, with different content

```
    var next = null;
    var outer = $('.twitter');
    var current = outer.find('.twitterinner:first');
    current.fadeIn();
    function fade() {
        if (current.next('div.twitterinner').length > 0) {
            next = current.next('div.twitterinner');
        } else {
            next = outer.find('div.twitterinner:first');
        }

        current.fadeOut(500);
        setTimeout(function(){
            next.FadeIn(500);
        },1000);
//      next.fadeIn(500);
        current = next;
        setTimeout(fade, 2000);
    }
    fade();
```

and the html

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 padding twitter">    
    <div class="twitterinner">Jellyfish Webdesign was afgelopen weekend aanwezig bij #YoutopiaArtsFestifal in het #Lloydhotel in A'dam! De website hebben we gesponsord.<br></div>
    <div class="twitterinner">Laat uw email adres achter via http://t.co/MHUXpcY1NE om op de hoogte te blijven van onze nieuwe website release. #Jellyfishux<br></div>
    <div class="twitterinner">Jellyfish Webdesign is vandaag officieel live gegaan! Voor meer informatie bezoek onze website, http://t.co/MHUXpcY1NE #jellyfishux<br></div>                
</div>
```

If i remove the setTimeout after the startup, it runs just fine (and i include again the fadeIn) but once I add the setTimeout with the fadein function in it, it stops working. I cant seem to find where I go wrong. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: `setTimeout` works *a-synch-ron-ous-ly*. Think about that `:)`

Comment: what if i told you that fade has a callback

Comment: `FadeIn != fadeIn` - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/poqga8w0/1/

Comment: i know, use fade then :)

Comment: Javascript is still new territorium for me sadly. Thanks for the great responds all. The fadeIn did it indeed for me. I am glad I see lots of alternative ways for this to solve, and to be honest, i never thought about using the `setInterval`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to use `setInterval()` instead of `setTimeout()` as your function is getting call repeatidly. See below code

**NOTE** - please correct spelling for `fadeIn(500)`, it starts with small `f`.

```
var next = null;
    var outer = $('.twitter');
    var current = outer.find('.twitterinner:first');
    current.fadeIn();
    function fade() {
        if (current.next('div.twitterinner').length > 0) {
            next = current.next('div.twitterinner');
        } else {
            next = outer.find('div.twitterinner:first');
        }

        current.fadeOut(500, function(){
           next.fadeIn(500);
            current = next;
        });
    }
   setInterval(fade,2000);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4v10agdq/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute something after an animation, you can do it like this (chaining)

```
current.fadeOut(500, function () {
    next.FadeIn(500);
    current = next;
});
```

To loop i suggest you to use interval instead of setTimeout.

```
setInterval(fade, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

In "FadeIn", "f" should be small

Your Code :

```
setTimeout(function(){
        next.FadeIn(500);
    },1000);
```

Actual Code :

```
setTimeout(function(){
        next.fadeIn(500);
    },1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with setInterval

```
var i = 0;

setInterval(function() {
    $(".twitterinner").fadeOut("fast");
           $(".twitterinner").eq(i).fadeIn("slow");

     i++;
    if(i == $(".twitterinner").length){
       i = 0;   
    }


} ,1000);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/g719eor3/1/)

Comment: Set interval is a nice way (something that never crossed my mind to be honest. Had to do some read up on it), but I must point out in your code didnt supplied the timeout i wanted in between the fadeout and back in. They overlapped and that wasn't the meaning. I did thumbsup you though for the idea of `setInterval`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use setInterval, but if you prefer to control it with a setTimeout, the better is to set just one timeout in the same time and chain your calls using callbacks.

Something like that :

```js
function fade() {
    if (current.next('div.twitterinner').length > 0) {
        next = current.next('div.twitterinner');
    } 
    else {
        next = outer.find('div.twitterinner:first');
    }

    current.fadeOut(500, function() {
        // executed after 500ms
        next.delay(500).fadeIn(500, function() {
            // executed after 500 + 500 +500 = 1500 ms;
            current = next;
            setTimeout(fade, 500); // executed after 1500 + 500 = 2000 ms.
        });
    });
}
```

or if you want to have a more clearer script to execute all of this, you can define a function for each step (this is useful if your animation become more complex) :

```js
function fade() {
    if (current.next('div.twitterinner').length > 0) {
        next = current.next('div.twitterinner');
    } 
    else {
        next = outer.find('div.twitterinner:first');
    }

    current.fadeOut(500, step2);

    function step2() {
        // executed after 500ms
        next.delay(500).fadeIn(500, step3);
    }

    function step3() {
        // executed after 500 + 500 +500 = 1500 ms;
        current = next;
        setTimeout(fade, 500); // executed after 1500 + 500 = 2000 ms.
    }
}
```